# cellArray to csv

Tags: matlab, csv, cell, export-to-csv, cell-array

I found a function (see below) that creates `.csv` out of a cell array. I modified it so as to work with a cellArray{z}{g} instead of a cellArray{z, s}. In the resulting `.csv` file, everything that should be separated into several columns is in one column. So I have only one column with several rows. I don't know how to separate these. In the cellArray{1}{1} for example contains first a String, and then values like 13.4156. How could I enable each cell in cellArray{z}{g} to end up in a separate cell in the`. csv` file?

```
  function cell2csv(filename, cellArray, delimiter)
  % Writes cell array content into a *.csv file.
  % 
  % CELL2CSV(filename,cellArray,delimiter)
  %
  % filename      = Name of the file to save. [ i.e. 'text.csv' ]
  % cellarray    = Name of the Cell Array where the data is in
  % delimiter = seperating sign, normally:',' (default)
  %
  % by Sylvain Fiedler, KA, 2004
  % modified by Rob Kohr, Rutgers, 2005 - changed to english and fixed delimiter
  if nargin<3
      delimiter = ',';
  end

  datei = fopen(filename,'w');
  for z=1:size(cellArray,1)
      for g=1:length(cellArray{z})
          var = eval(['cellArray{z}{g}']);

         if size(var,1) == 0
            var = '';
          end

        if isnumeric(var) == 1
            var = num2str(var);
        end

        fprintf(datei,var);

      end
      fprintf(datei,'\n');
  end
  fclose(datei);
```

Comment: Why did you delete the previous question? Which version of MATLAB is this? Which OS? Can you use `xlswrite`? It deals with mixed data types much better than `dlmwrite` or `csvwrite` (which you _should_ be using)...

Comment: First, I think I wrote this question under a different title where I wanted to ask another question. My bad. When I try xlswrite('filename', cellArray) it complains that it cannot convert to a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code below:

```
A = cell(3,1);
for ind1 = 1:3
  A{ind1} = {ind1,ind1,'cat'};
end

%% Approach 1 - xlswrite
B = vertcat(A{:});
xlswrite('somefile.xls',B);

%% Approach 2 - printf
% A is 3x1 cell of (1x3 cell) objects
B = cellfun(@(x)[num2str(x) ','], vertcat(A{:}),'UniformOutput',false);
% B is 3x3 cell of (1x1 cell) objects
C = num2cell(B,2);
% C is 1x3 cell of (3x1 cell) objects
fid = fopen('somefile.csv','w');
for ind1 = 1:size(C,1)
  fprintf(fid, '%s\n',[C{ind1}{:}]);
end
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by changing fprintf(datei,var); --> fprintf(datei,[var, ',']);
and then when opening the csv just use , as delimiter